# Rel attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, lightbox

I have the lightbox gallery view script and is working fine.

In my site I use an ajax script to call another page and load it into a DIV

For Example:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('loadmailfunctions');
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText; sizeit();
    setVisibility('uploads', 'block'); settotime();
  }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "profile/photos.inc.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

This then loads all the photos I need but when I click on a photo and use the rel="lightbox" it does not work.

Is this something to do with the parent DOM / window or something? Sorry bit of a noob, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

In the loaded page profile/photos.inc.php, I have this code:

```
echo '<li><a href="',$row['localdirectory'],$row['photo'],'" rel="lightbox" ><img src="',$row['localdirectory'],$row['photo'],'" style="width:110px; height:85px;" alt="" /></a></li>'
```

But does not execute the Lighbox viewer script.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? This is incredibly vague. Nothing in your code has anything to do with HTML's `rel` attribute.

Comment: In the loaded page profile/photos.inc.php, I have this code

Comment: In the loaded page profile/photos.inc.php, I have this code

echo'<li><a href="',$row['localdirectory'],$row['photo'],'" rel="lightbox" ><img src="',$row['localdirectory'],$row['photo'],'" style="width:110px; height:85px;" alt="" /></a></li>

But does not execute the Lighbox viewer script

Comment: I was hoping when the link is clicked that it will open up the larger image in the lightbox gallery view but it will not work, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox activates after page load, it scans DOM tree searching for anchors with `rel="lightbox"` attribute and binds `onclick` event to them. When you perform AJAX call, new elements are added to DOM tree, but you have to manually initialize scanning for new anchors.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, so how would I initialize a scan for new anchors? Do I add a method at the end of the Ajax call?

Comment: You should call it after `ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;` but I don't know what kind of lightbox library you are using so I can not provide exact code for it.

Answer (score 0):

As dev-null-dweller implied, the Lightbox usage example only activates `rel="lightbox"` links on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox({
    overlayBgColor: '#FFF',
    overlayOpacity: 0.6,
    imageLoading: 'http://example.com/images/loading.gif',
    imageBtnClose: 'http://example.com/images/close.gif',
    imageBtnPrev: 'http://example.com/images/prev.gif',
    imageBtnNext: 'http://example.com/images/next.gif',
    containerResizeSpeed: 350,
    txtImage: 'Imagem',
    txtOf: 'de'
   });
});
</script>
```

You should re-run this for new elements that have magically appeared in your `div` after Ajaxifying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lightBoxOptions = {
    overlayBgColor: '#FFF',
    overlayOpacity: 0.6,
    imageLoading: 'http://example.com/images/loading.gif',
    imageBtnClose: 'http://example.com/images/close.gif',
    imageBtnPrev: 'http://example.com/images/prev.gif',
    imageBtnNext: 'http://example.com/images/next.gif',
    containerResizeSpeed: 350,
    txtImage: 'Imagem',
    txtOf: 'de'
};

$(function() {
   // Set Lightbox handlers on "static" elements
   $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(lightBoxOptions);
});

// then, whereever your AJAX code is:
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('loadmailfunctions');
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText; sizeit();
    setVisibility('uploads', 'block'); settotime();

    // Set Lightbox handlers on new elements
    $('#loadmailfunctions a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(lightBoxOptions);
  }
}
</script>
```

Incidentally, if you're using the lightbox jQuery plugin (and I have to assume that you are, since you haven't specified otherwise), why aren't you using jQuery as a whole?

If you're *not* using the jQuery plugin, then repeat your event handler setup in a similar way.

Comment: Great thanks, Yes I am using lightbox jQuery plugin, ill give this a try. thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does the `@` in `a[@rel*=lightbox]` mean?

Comment: @Rocket: I have no idea, frankly. [The jQuery documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) doesn't mention it, but [the jQuery Lightbox plugin documentation and usage examples](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) seem quite happy with it, and that's a widely-used plugin by all accounts. So I'll leave the specific selector up to them.

Comment: @Rocket: Possibly related to [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) (though it seems like that would mean no jQuery lightboxes work any more): "Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style selectors were removed (they were previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2). Simply remove the “@” symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again." I'm still leaving it up to the plugin authors, though. I'm just _extending_ their usage example, not rewriting it.

Comment: @Rocket: Ah, last lightbox release 17 November, 2007. [jQuery was at v1.2 at the time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history) Seems odd that this still works for people. Maybe I've got the wrong plugin.

Comment: @Wayne: Can you provide a reference to the _actual_ plug-in that you're using? You never really said.

Comment: Hmm I tried your fix as above but did not work and a little daunting as a noob, I was doing some research on refreshing the DOM tree, can jqueryLive do this? Or would there be an easier way of refreshing the DOM after the ajax DIV is loaded?

Comment: I am using the lightbox jQuery plugin

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: `code`
function makeajaxlinks() {       
//Run a function for each link
$$('a').each(function(item){ 
//If the event was already made - delete it!
item.removeEvents('click'); 
//for each of the links add an onClick event
item.addEvent('click', function(e) {
//Pass URL we are going to get
send_request(this.getProperty("href"));
makeajaxlinks();
//Keep the browser from going to the link location
e.stop();
//return false;                   
});
});
}
`code`

Comment: I made the above as a function then called makeajaxlinks(); after my AJAX innerHTML DIV call but that didnt do the trick.

Comment: @Wayne: I thought about `live`, but `lightbox` is not an event.

Comment: For the record, the plug-in you're using is indeed the one I was using as a reference. So, if my answer didn't work, I've made a mistake somewhere (or the plug-in doesn't behave as I'd expect). I'll revisit this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks very much Tomalak its a great help :)

Comment: @Wayne: That code is for MooTools, not jQuery (though it looks very similar). Can you show us, in a pastebin, the precise code you used when you tried mine?

Comment: Hi Tomalak,

Pastebin link as requested below
http://pastebin.com/iWF73BdJ


I wasnt sure where to add your fix so i added just under my AJAX call.


Thanks

Wayne

Comment: @Wayne: Yea, I suspected as much. The entire purpose is to put the `.lightBox` call into the AJAX on-success handler, [like this](http://pastebin.com/QpzN11vS). BTW you really should start indenting your code, so that it actually becomes legible. And... if you're using jQuery for some things, why not [use jQuery for the AJAX too](http://pastebin.com/J3sXnmmq)? Instead of that terribly ugly `try`/`catch` nesting. **And, please, next time you aren't sure where to put the fix, _tell me_; don't just take a random guess then say "it doesn't work".**

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I just wanted to give you some feedback with the script. I added the JS as advised and the script fails so i presume the new anchors are not being added to the DOM tree upon succession of the AJAX call. Again thanks for your help its much appreciated.

Comment: @Wayne: Alright, well we'd need to know what `profile/photos.inc.php` contains. You'll have to perform some debugging to find out whether there are matching nodes after insertion of the AJAX-requested data to the DOM tree.